# valign="top" is not working in outlook email client in case of 1st table has lengthy data

Tags: html, email, outlook, html-email

I am designing a responsive email which has 3 table tag parallel inside a table. Each table has some data in their respective td. I want data to be valign="top" in every case if any table has any kind of data. But I am facing weird issue here, I have good amount of data in 1st table which is causing to break the other table's alignment, next table's data is not keep aligned top in case of 1st table has lengthy data. I am enclosing my markup here alongwith screenshot of outlook email how it looks on outlook. I am using Outlook 2010.

```
Image how it looks in outlook : http://i40.tinypic.com/ioqc60.jpg
```

```
<html>       <head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Test Email</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
</head>
<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<style type="text/css">
    /****** EMAIL CLIENT BUG FIXES - BEST NOT TO CHANGE THESE ********/
    /* Forces Hotmail to display emails at full width. */
    .ExternalClass {width:100%;}
    .ReadMsgBody {width: 100%;}

    /* Forces Hotmail to display normal line spacing. */
    .ExternalClass, .ExternalClass p, .ExternalClass span, .ExternalClass font, .ExternalClass td, .ExternalClass div {line-height:100%;}

    /* Prevents Webkit and Windows Mobile platforms from changing default font sizes. */
    body {-webkit-text-size-adjust:none; -ms-text-size-adjust:none;}

    /* Resets all body margins and padding to "0" for good measure. */
    body {margin:0; padding:0;}

    /* Resolves webkit padding issue. */
    table {border-spacing:0;}

    /* Resolves the Outlook 2007, 2010, and Gmail td padding issue. */
    table td {border-collapse:collapse;}

    /****** END BUG FIXES ********/

    /* Reset Styles */
    table, p, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, strong, a, font { font-family: Futura, "Trebuchet MS", Arial, sans-serif!important; }
    h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {line-height:100%;}
    p {margin:0; padding:0;}

    body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        color: #666666;
    }

    h3, h4, h5 {
        letter-spacing: -1px;
    }

    a img {border: none!important;}
    .container {
        display: block!important;
        width: 100%!important;
        max-width: 600px!important;
        margin: 0 auto!important;
        padding: 5px!important;
        clear: both!important;
        font-family: Futura, "Trebuchet MS", Arial, sans-serif;
    }
    .content {
        margin: 20px 0;
    }

    table {
        padding: 0 5px;

    }

    td {
        font-size: 11px;
    }

    tr {
        border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc !important;
    }

    .middle {
    }
    .bbb-blue {
        color: #2D368C;
    }
    .header .bbb-hdr-logo {
        width: 40%;
    }
    .header .bbb-hdr-message {
        width: 50%;
    }
    .header h3 {
        margin: 0 0 12px 0;
        font-size: 40px;
    }
    .header p {
        margin: 0;
    }
    img.remove {
        float: left;
    }

    img.rating {
        margin-left: 10px;
    }

    .cta img.seeDetails {
        margin: 0 4px 0 0;
    }

    .copy {
        font-size: 16px;
    }
    .price span {
        font-size: 20px;
    }
    .price sup {
        font-size: 10px;
    }
    .main .content .upc {
        font-size: 11px;
    }
    .main .content .product-img {
        width: 20%;
    }
    .main .content .product-details {
        width: 70%;
    }
    .main .content .my-table-item {
        width: 50%;
    }

    .footer .content td a {
        color: #2D368C;
        font-size: 16px;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    @media (max-width: 580px) {
        .header .content,
        .header .content table,
        .main .content,
        .main .content table {
            width: 100%!important;
        }
        .main .content .section-hdr h3{
            font-size: 16px!important;
        }
        .middle {
            border-left: none;
            border-right: none;     
        }
    }
    </style>
    <!-- Template Wrapper -->

    <table class="container" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="590" align="center">

        <!-- content section -->
        <tr>
            <td class="main" style="border-top:3px solid #F5F5F5;border-bottom:3px solid #F5F5F5;padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:10px;margin-bottom:20px;">
                <table class="content" width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="padding:5px;" align="left">
                            <table width="180" align="left" class="content left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                <tr>
                                    <td width="50%" valign="top">
                                        <div class="section-wrapper" width="100%" border="0">
                                            <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="width:40px"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/ebpt2cl.gif"></td>
                                                    <td style="font-size:10px;">Dyson Mini-Turbine...<br>$69.99</td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="width:40px"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/ebpt2cl.gif"></td>
                                                    <td style="font-size:10px;">Dyson Mini-Turbine...<br>$69.99</td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="width:40px"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/ebpt2cl.gif"></td>
                                                    <td style="font-size:10px;">Dyson Mini-Turbine...<br>$69.99</td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="width:40px"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/ebpt2cl.gif"></td>
                                                    <td style="font-size:10px;">Dyson Mini-Turbine...<br>$69.99</td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="width:40px"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/ebpt2cl.gif"></td>
                                                    <td style="font-size:10px;">Dyson Mini-Turbine...<br>$69.99</td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="width:40px"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/ebpt2cl.gif"></td>
                                                    <td style="font-size:10px;">Dyson Mini-Turbine...<br>$69.99</td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="width:40px"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/ebpt2cl.gif"></td>
                                                    <td style="font-size:10px;">Dyson Mini-Turbine...<br>$69.99</td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="width:40px"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/ebpt2cl.gif"></td>
                                                    <td style="font-size:10px;">Dyson Mini-Turbine...<br>$69.99</td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="width:40px"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/ebpt2cl.gif"></td>
                                                    <td style="font-size:10px;">Dyson Mini-Turbine...<br>$69.99</td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="width:40px"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/ebpt2cl.gif"></td>
                                                    <td style="font-size:10px;">Dyson Mini-Turbine...<br>$69.99</td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="width:40px"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/ebpt2cl.gif"></td>
                                                    <td style="font-size:10px;">Dyson Mini-Turbine...<br>$69.99</td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="width:40px"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/ebpt2cl.gif"></td>
                                                    <td style="font-size:10px;">Dyson Mini-Turbine...<br>$69.99</td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="width:40px"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/ebpt2cl.gif"></td>
                                                    <td style="font-size:10px;">Dyson Mini-Turbine...<br>$69.99</td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="width:40px"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/ebpt2cl.gif"></td>
                                                    <td style="font-size:10px;">Dyson Mini-Turbine...<br>$69.99</td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="width:40px"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/ebpt2cl.gif"></td>
                                                    <td style="font-size:10px;">Dyson Mini-Turbine...<br>$69.99</td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="width:40px"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/ebpt2cl.gif"></td>
                                                    <td style="font-size:10px;">Dyson Mini-Turbine...<br>$69.99</td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="width:40px"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/ebpt2cl.gif"></td>
                                                    <td style="font-size:10px;">Dyson Mini-Turbine...<br>$69.99</td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="width:40px"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/ebpt2cl.gif"></td>
                                                    <td style="font-size:10px;">Dyson Mini-Turbine...<br>$69.99</td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="width:40px"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/ebpt2cl.gif"></td>
                                                    <td style="font-size:10px;">Dyson Mini-Turbine...<br>$69.99</td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="width:40px"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/ebpt2cl.gif"></td>
                                                    <td style="font-size:10px;">Dyson Mini-Turbine...<br>$69.99</td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="width:40px"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/ebpt2cl.gif"></td>
                                                    <td style="font-size:10px;">Dyson Mini-Turbine...<br>$69.99</td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="width:40px"><img     src="http://i.imgur.com/ebpt2cl.gif"></td>
                                                    <td style="font-size:10px;">Dyson Mini-Turbine...<br>$69.99</td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="width:40px"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/ebpt2cl.gif"></td>
                                                    <td style="font-size:10px;">Dyson Mini-Turbine...<br>$69.99</td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="width:40px"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/ebpt2cl.gif"></td>
                                                    <td style="font-size:10px;">Dyson Mini-Turbine...<br>$69.99</td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="width:40px"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/ebpt2cl.gif"></td>
                                                    <td style="font-size:10px;">Dyson Mini-Turbine...<br>$69.99</td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="width:40px"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/ebpt2cl.gif"></td>
                                                    <td style="font-size:10px;">Dyson Mini-Turbine...<br>$69.99</td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="width:40px"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/ebpt2cl.gif"></td>
                                                    <td style="font-size:10px;">Dyson Mini-Turbine...<br>$69.99</td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="width:40px"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/ebpt2cl.gif"></td>
                                                    <td style="font-size:10px;">Dyson Mini-Turbine...<br>$69.99</td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="width:40px"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/ebpt2cl.gif"></td>
                                                    <td style="font-size:10px;">Dyson Mini-Turbine...<br>$69.99</td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="width:40px"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/ebpt2cl.gif"></td>
                                                    <td style="font-size:10px;">Dyson Mini-Turbine...<br>$69.99</td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="width:40px"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/ebpt2cl.gif"></td>
                                                    <td style="font-size:10px;">Dyson Mini-Turbine...<br>$69.99</td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="width:40px"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/ebpt2cl.gif"></td>
                                                    <td style="font-size:10px;">Dyson Mini-Turbine...<br>$69.99</td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="width:40px"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/ebpt2cl.gif"></td>
                                                    <td style="font-size:10px;">Dyson Mini-Turbine...<br>$69.99</td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="width:40px"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/ebpt2cl.gif"></td>
                                                    <td style="font-size:10px;">Dyson Mini-Turbine...<br>$69.99</td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="width:40px"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/ebpt2cl.gif"></td>
                                                    <td style="font-size:10px;">Dyson Mini-Turbine...<br>$69.99</td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="width:40px"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/ebpt2cl.gif"></td>
                                                    <td style="font-size:10px;">Dyson Mini-Turbine...<br>$69.99</td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="width:40px"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/ebpt2cl.gif"></td>
                                                    <td style="font-size:10px;">Dyson Mini-Turbine...<br>$69.99</td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="width:40px"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/ebpt2cl.gif"></td>
                                                    <td style="font-size:10px;">Dyson Mini-Turbine...<br>$69.99</td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="width:40px"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/ebpt2cl.gif"></td>
                                                    <td style="font-size:10px;">Dyson Mini-Turbine...<br>$69.99</td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="width:40px"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/ebpt2cl.gif"></td>
                                                    <td style="font-size:10px;">Dyson Mini-Turbine...<br>$69.99</td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="width:40px"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/ebpt2cl.gif"></td>
                                                    <td style="font-size:10px;">Dyson Mini-Turbine...<br>$69.99</td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="width:40px"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/ebpt2cl.gif"></td>
                                                    <td style="font-size:10px;">Dyson Mini-Turbine...<br>$69.99</td>
                                                </tr>                                                
                                            </table>
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                            <table width="180" align="left" class="content middle" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                <tr>
                                    <td width="50%" valign="top">
                                        <div class="section-wrapper" width="100%" border="0">

                                            <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="width:40px"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/ebpt2cl.gif"></td>
                                                    <td style="font-size:10px;">Dyson Mini-Turbine...<br>$69.99</td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="width:40px"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/ebpt2cl.gif"></td>
                                                    <td style="font-size:10px;">Dyson Mini-Turbine...<br>$69.99</td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="width:40px"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/ebpt2cl.gif"></td>
                                                    <td style="font-size:10px;">Dyson Mini-Turbine...<br>$69.99</td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="width:40px"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/ebpt2cl.gif"></td>
                                                    <td style="font-size:10px;">Dyson Mini-Turbine...<br>$69.99</td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="width:40px"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/ebpt2cl.gif"></td>
                                                    <td style="font-size:10px;">Dyson Mini-Turbine...<br>$69.99</td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </table>

                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                            <table width="180" align="left" class="content right" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                <tr>
                                    <td width="50%" valign="top">
                                        <div class="section-wrapper" width="100%" border="0">

                                            <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="width:40px"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/ebpt2cl.gif"></td>
                                                    <td style="font-size:10px;">Dyson Mini-Turbine...<br>$69.99</td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="width:40px"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/ebpt2cl.gif"></td>
                                                    <td style="font-size:10px;">Dyson Mini-Turbine...<br>$69.99</td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="width:40px"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/ebpt2cl.gif"></td>
                                                    <td style="font-size:10px;">Dyson Mini-Turbine...<br>$69.99</td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="width:40px"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/ebpt2cl.gif"></td>
                                                    <td style="font-size:10px;">Dyson Mini-Turbine...     <br>$69.99</td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="width:40px"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/ebpt2cl.gif"></td>
                                                    <td style="font-size:10px;">Dyson Mini-Turbine...<br>$69.99</td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="width:40px"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/ebpt2cl.gif"></td>
                                                    <td style="font-size:10px;">Dyson Mini-Turbine...<br>$69.99</td>
                                                </tr>                                                
                                            </table>
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Why are you using three tables in the first place? You could use `colspan` to force them to all align to the top of the columns, if you are willing to use *one table*.

Comment: As I mentioned I am designing responsive layout. So I want each table to align 100% on small screens. That means on mobile each table come vertically one after another.

Answer (score 3):

Put `valign="top"` on the `<td>` that contains the 3 parent tables. You currently only have it on the table cells containing your section-wrapper divs.

```
<!-- content section -->
<tr>
    <td class="main" style="border-top:3px solid #F5F5F5;border-bottom:3px solid #F5F5F5;padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:10px;margin-bottom:20px;">
        <table class="content" width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
                <td style="padding:5px;" align="left" valign="top"><!-- < PUT IT HERE! -->
                    <table width="180" align="left" class="content left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                        <tr>
                            <td width="50%" valign="top">
                                <div class="section-wrapper" width="100%" border="0">
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion John, I have tried this but it is also not working, resulting same issue as I am facing previously.

Answer (score 0):

I have had same issue before, its like outlook cant fit 3x 33.33% next to each other.
I had to make them all 32% to make them fit side by side. Its like outlook makes a big invis border around the tds